# Visual Studio Project Item Template can't add reference assembly to .NET 5 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

We have a item template that adds one of our DLLs as a reference to the target project. The item can be added to a C# or VB.NET project. I can add the item to a .NET Framework project without any issues. But when I add the item to a .NET 5 project, I get the error "*The reference EntityModel could not be added to the project. This wizard will continue to run, but the resulting project may not build properly*". I can add the DLL manually to the .NET 5 project without any problems.

```
  <TemplateContent>
    <References>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Data</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>EntityModel</Assembly>
      </Reference>
    </References>
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.lcm" ReplaceParameters="false" CustomTool="MyModelGenerator">Model.lcm</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
```

As a test, I did try adding a `<HintPath>` with a hard coded path to the assembly but that didn't help either.

Any suggestions on what I need to change to avoid getting the error with .NET 5 projects?

Comment: re-target your source for the template to .net core

Comment: Hi @Jazb, I'm new templates. I'm not sure what you mean by "re-target the source for the template". Do you mean there's an option in the vstemplate file that specifies the target .NET version (eg TargetFrameworkVersion)?